# Why are all booleans in the database true?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to validate certain data and then store it as True in the database after validation. But when I click the button after validation, all the data becomes True. But I just want to check all data individually and set it to true. I'm a beginner, it would be great if someone could help me.

```
views.py
def approve(request):
    form = QuesModel.objects.filter(flaag__exact="False")

    if request.POST.get("next") == "next":

        form.update(flaag=True) # here all false become true. What I don't want


    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'approve.html', context)
```

```
approve.html
 <form method="POST" action=""> 
            {% for event in form %}

                {% if  forloop.counter <= 1 %}
                {% csrf_token %}
                    .....
```

```
model.py
class Model(models.Model):
 .....
 .....
 flaag = models.BooleanField('Aprroved', default=False)
```

Comment: Try to use `False` instead of `"False"`.

Comment: Nevertheless, all false become true

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to set the value of flaag for all False instances to True? Or what do you actually want to change?

Comment: @replaalpi: well that is what your view is saying: to set all instances to `True`... It is not clear what you aim to achieve, what the form looks like, etc.

Comment: I have four rows (different contents) in the database, for example that when the function is executed, only row one becomes True, but all four rows become True

Answer (score 0):

you are getting all rows in Queryset(form variable) which has `flaag== Flase`,
And `form.update(flaag=True)` it's performing bulk update on all object present in Queryset.

Now, if you want to update only one row you can use first() on filter query

`form = QuesModel.objects.filter(flaag__exact="False").first()`

so, in form variable now you have only one object of model and it update that one object only